# directory not found for option - Upgrade Swift 2.0

Tags: xcode, swift

I have this problem ?

`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'`

I have checked in the Library Search Paths and in Framework search paths but I found nothing.

How can I solve my problem ?

Comment: When do you have this  error ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: is always present. This warming is released after updating to swift 2.0
is a worming and I'm trying to delete it. I think it is referring to a framework does not exist.

Comment: Di you perform a deep clean in Xcode ?

Answer (score 4):

You can perform a deep clean within `Xcode` by doing the following:

```
command+alt+maj+K
```

You should also check what you have in your `Header Search Paths`.
If you have `$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks` in your `Framework Search Paths`, delete it.

Comment: You should verify that you don't have any extra search path, please see the updated answer

Comment: i checked the path "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks" and the Frameworks folder does not exist. 
I created the folder Frameworks and now there is the worming
Thank you

Comment: The framework shouldn't exist, that what is wrong in your case, you should correct the path, did you try what a exposed in my answer ? Somewhere in you build settings there is a reference to this path, which doesn't exit.

Comment: in my folder
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks

i have 

DTPerformanceSession.framework
InterfaceBuilderKit.framework

Comment: No you should check in your Xcode build settings, under library search path, framework search path, header search path both of your target and project

Answer (score 0):

In "**Build Settings**" you might find a target "**YourAppTests**". 
Under

> "search paths" > "Framework Search Paths"

change

> "iphoneos/Developer/Library/Frameworks"

to

> "iphoneos/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks"

.